# Ask and answer dialogs don't appear after being compiled

Tags: windows, dialog, hidden, livecode

In Windows 10, everything works perfectly in the Livecode editor (64 bit).  However, after building/compiling, ask and answer dialogs are hidden or behind other items in the stack and do not show.

How can I fix this? I need answer and ask dialogs to appear like they should. I tried 32 bit - same problem.

I can't seem to find anything in the build options that would fix this.

Thank you for any help.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the ask and answer dialog assets are not being included in the build. Try this:

1. Open the Standalone Application Settings from the File menu.
2. Go to the General tab.
3. Click the radio button "Select inclusions for the standalone application".
4. Go to the Inclusions tab.
5. Scroll down until you find the Answer Dialog and Ask Dialog options, and check those.

Re-build your project and see if that solves the problem. Please note that if you choose to select inclusions manually you will have to check all of the libraries, widgets, and other assets that you are using in the stack.

When the "Search for required inclusions" option is chosen in the General tab, the Standalone Application Builder is supposed to scan the stack contents and include everything that's needed automatically. But it doesn't always catch everything, so many experienced LiveCode developers always do this step manually.

Comment: I had already done that, but thank you.  In the end, I went to a older build that did compile properly and rebuilt the entire project on that - and it worked!!  I have no clue as to why the project would not work properly after compiling.  It's bizarre.

Comment: Possibly a bug in the version of LiveCode you were using. Which version failed, and which one succeeded?

Comment: I am using the latest stable version - business license.  It happens on compile only.

Comment: A new Release Candidate just came out--9.6RC2. It's worth testing with that version to see if it still fails.